# Unknown size vector input

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, input

here is the question.
I have a vector of ints, and user should enter it's elements as long as he or she want. Then, this vector is passed to a function, which calculates it's size for whatever reason. Is there any way to do so? I found some code on shores of the Internet:

```
std::vector<int> vec;

std::string buffer = "";

std::cout << "Enter numbers. "
          << "After you finish, enter newline" << std::endl;

do {
    std::getline(std::cin, buffer);
    if (buffer.size() > 0) {
        vec.push_back(atoi(buffer.c_str())); //stoi was not declared =(
    }
} while (buffer != "");

foo(vec);
....
void foo(std::vector<int> &input)
{
    for (const int &i : input)
        {
            std::cout << i << endl;
        }
}
```

But this code doesn't works in right way: I choose entering numbers and it just does nothing. Have no idea what's wrong with it.
(c++11 enabled)

Comment: What do you mean by "it does nothing"? Do you mean nothing is pushed back to the vector? There is an inconsistency between the `std::vector` variable names `vec` and `input` in the question too by the way.

Comment: argh, forgod to change while copypaste;

it just doesn't give me even a chance to enter something

Comment: What happens when the user enters "frog" instead of a number?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it is not supposed to happen (or will be fixed later :))
Also, as I said before, with this code user doesn't have even a option to enter something

Comment: @ThomasMatthews `atoi()` will return `0` for that.

Comment: Where is the function that calculates the size?

Comment: @Barmar: What I am alluding to is that there is no checking for quality input.  If I type in "frog", then a zero is entered, which is probably unexpected.

Comment: I tested this code in MSVC and g++ and in both cases it works as intended, your issue must be elsewhere - please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: What does "I choose entering numbers" mean? Is there another user input before running this code? You need to show a complete but minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Barmar nothing will broke if I change this range-based loop to default for loop

Comment: @interjay I think it means he's not fluent in English and didn't word it clearly.

Comment: Just created a new project with minimum, complete and verifiable code and I can enter something. Need to fflush before do-while.

Another problem is that vector is not readed correctly
http://pastebin.com/A5QJX64F
input: 1 2 3 4 5
expected output: 1 2 3 4 5
output: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add items to a vector until there is no more input (or until a sentinel value is entered), usage of `std::istringstream` and `operator >>` could be used:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    std::string buffer;
    int data;
    std::getline(std::cin, buffer);
    std::istringstream iss(buffer);
    while (iss >> data)
          vec.push_back(data);
    foo(vec);   
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/5u8fEo)

Comment: This won't stop when the user enters a blank line, he has to type the EOF character.

Comment: Oops, I misread. This requires him to type all the numbers on a single line, instead of one per line as in his original code.

Comment: Well, looks like it is what I have searched for, thanks!

Comment: @Barmar, your rep had me doubting the answer :)